# Page Manager and Panels settings — where do they live?

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

I'm continuing my quest to make every piece of common site architecture into something that can be displayed in a View. Right now I'm on Panels panes and Page Manager pages.

I have a site that is most assuredly making use of Panels panes and Page Manager pages on the node display, node edit form, and a few other places. However, when I inspect `page_manager_pages`, or any other table in the DB that begins with `page_manager_` or `panels_`, the table appears to be completely empty. (I'm using PHPMyAdmin, and it gives me that red cursor with an 'x' in it.)

I haven't been able to find an API call that lists all Panels panes, Page Manager pages, or other relevant data either. And when I have looked through the sites I own to see ones that *do* have something in the `page_manager_pages` or `panel_panes` tables, it seems to be much less than I would expect. (E.g. a large site that is **heavily** themed with Page Manager and Panels shows up in the db with just two entries in the `page_manager_pages` table.)

I've even combed through the SQL queries that Drupal does when I click "enable" on a disabled Page Manager page (e.g. the node edit form, the node display), but haven't found anything that looks meaningful.

Comment: Are you sure, the you have privileges to read the data from the database? Because, when I checked on my database as a _root_ user, the tables `page_manager_handlers` and `page_manager_pages` have serialized entries of the settings of the panel pages. So, turns out the settings are being saved in  the database.

Comment: I've never used it, but I think panels relies on ctools - which might suggest those settings are stored as ctools plugins?

Comment: I didn't see any relevant tables with 'ctools' in the name either. Also, I'm pretty sure I have privileges. I've pulled out and unserialized blobs from other tables as part of this same project (e.g. nodetype settings, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up requiring API calls, since Panels and Page Manager definitions can live in code or in the database.

First I got the tasks with `page_manager_get_tasks()`.

This gave me a list of tasks, which appear to be high-level Page Manager stuff. My Workbench, Node add/edit form, Node template, User template, User edit form, and Custom Page were the tasks.

Custom Page had subtasks that included all my custom pages, so I did `page_manager_get_task_subtasks()` on each tasks that had subtasks, and then `page_manager_load_task_handlers()` on each subtask. Within the handlers, there is information about the Panels and other objects that go on that page.